# Generic XSLT Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I am a fresh bee in XSLT.  I have a time constraint where I have to deliver something very urgently.

I am pasting the xml samples below. Here is small explanation I have input.xml and output.xml. these both files need to be merged as they have different formats. both files need to be merged based on element "ID". output.xml need to merged inside input.xml. if the ID of an element in input.xml matches with element ID of output.xml then child elements of output.xml need to be merged before the end tag of the matched element in the input.xml.

If you have any questions please fire them back.

## input.xml

```
<Result ID="A">
  <Comment>Blah blah blah.</Comment>
  <aaa>111</aaa>
  <a1>000</a1>
  <a2 ID="B">
  <a2a>9iu</a2a>
  <a23>kjf</a23>
  <b ID="C">
    <b1>k</b1>
  </b>
  <c>jjj</c>
  <d ID="E">
    <d12>ppp</d12>
    <d23 ID="W" />
  </d>
  <e ID="AA">
    <d ID="G">
      <d12>ppp</d12>
      <d23 ID="O" />
    </d>
  </e>
</Result>
```

## output.xml

```
<Insert>
  <mn ID="A">
    <mn1>345</mn1>
    <mn2>123</mn2>
  </mn>
  <no ID="C">
    <op>09</op>
    <io>89</io>
  </no>
  <ab ID="B">
    <ab>jik</ab>
    <dc>hdg</dc>
  </ab>
</Insert>
```

## merged.xml (The required output):

```
<Result ID="A">
  <Comment>Blah blah blah.</Comment>
  <aaa>111</aaa>
  <a1>000</a1>
  <a2 ID="B">
    <a2a>9iu</a2a>
    <a23>kjf</a23>
    <b ID="C">
      <b1>k</b1>
      <op>09</op>
      <io>89</io>
    </b>
    <c>jjj</c>
    <d ID="E">
      <d12>ppp</d12>
      <d23 ID="W" />
    </d>
    <ab>jik</ab>
    <dc>hdg</dc>
  </a2>
  <e ID="AA">
    <d ID="G">
      <d12>ppp</d12>
      <d23 ID="O" />
    </d>
  </e>
  <mn1>345</mn1>
  <mn2>123</mn2>
</Result>
```

I need a generic XSLT solution which will work without hardcoded tag names.

Comment: urgently ?? very abstract title .. LOL

Answer (score 3):

You should check below links which explains in details of XML and XSLT

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xsl.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=simple&xsltfile=simple

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.asp

Sample
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xsl
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simplexsl.xml